# Recursive abstract ToString() in base class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism

Look at the following (pseudo) pattern:

```
public abstract class Animal {

     public abstract AnimalType { get; }

     public abstract override string ToString() {
          return String.Format("{0}={1}", AnimalType, this.ToString());
                                                         ^
                                                // does this even work?
     }

}
```

which would force every class that derives from it look like this:

```
public sealed class Horse : Animal {

     // horse specific declaration
     private string _name;
     private int    _age;

     // forced
     public override AnimalType { 
          get { return AnimalType.Horse; } 
     }

     // horse specific declaration
     public Name {
          get { return _name; }

     public Horse(string name, string age) {
          _name = name;
          _age  = age;
     }

     // forced
     public override string ToString() {
          return String.Format("{0}({1}", _name, _age);
     }
```

}

which would produce the following output:

```
Horse =MyHorseName(3);
Tiger =SomeOtherAttributesBecauseTigerIsDifferent
```

Problem is: When I want to force ToString() in the derived class, I can't have any functionality in the base class. I want the derived class to provide it's own string representation of itself, but still want to have a string representation that tells me, in this case, what type of animal it is.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: `public abstract override string ToString()`????????????? OMG, this surpasses all my expectations :-)

Comment: Can you maybe explain why you want to force overriding and provide (overriden) base functionality? (From what I understand - your solution might be what you want already, having part of the data in the base/generally formatted and part in the subclasses.)

Comment: Do you mean base.tostring()?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It is legal to make an `abstract override` method, and it can make sense with `ToString`, but of course **it is not legal for an `abstract` method to have a body**.

Comment: @AndreasReiff My solution is not legal. DarinDimitrov mentions why. ;)

Comment: Saying `public abstract override string ToString();` with a semicolon `;` is legal and can make sense in *some* situations. Saying `public abstract override string ToString() { ... }` with a body `{ ... }` is nonsense because `abstract` means "no implementation given here". The comment by @DarinDimitrov did not show `{}`, and not `;` either, but there were a lot of question marks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet is to declare and call a separate `protected abstract string GetAttributes()` method. In addition, you can use `sealed` to prevent subclasses from overriding the `ToString()` implementation:

```
public abstract class Animal {
     public abstract AnimalType { get; }

     public sealed override string ToString() {
          return String.Format("{0}={1}", AnimalType, this.GetAttributes());
     }

    protected abstract string GetAttributes();
}

public sealed class Horse {
    protected override string GetAttributes() {
        return String.Format("{0}({1}", _name, _age);
    }
}
```

If `Horse` attempted to override `ToString` at this point, it would receive a compile error. Meanwhile, it's forced to implement `GetAttributes`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll stick with your suggestion, although it could be confusing that the "ToString()" method of the derived class only gives a string representation of the base class while "GetAttributes()" serves this purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know maybe push the variables used in the ToString code up the base class with some default values, but have the child classes change them. So the ToString() code in base class wont need to be overriden but will provide custom outputs as the base class variables keep changing to whatever the child wants them to be. for example consider this:

```
  abstract class cbase
  {
    internal string _var1 = "def1", _var2 = "def2";

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return string.Format("{0} - {1}", _var1, _var2);

    }
  }
  class cchild1 : cbase
  {

    public cchild1()
    {
      _var1 = "umm";
      _var2 = "ok";

    }
  }
  class cchild2 : cbase
  {

  }
```

so for the above code:

```
new cchild1().ToString()
```

will output

```
umm - OK
```

while

```
new cchild2().ToString()
```

will output:

```
def1 - def2
```

so in this way, you dont have to override ToString in each child class but still the output format stays consistent in all inherited classes as you have defined in the base class. But you also have the liberty to override the ToString if there is a need.